# Can jQuery-UI safely be used without the CSS assets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-cdn

Can jQuery-UI safely be used without including the CSS assets?  [Google hosts the JS file](https://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI), but I don't see any references on that page to the jQuery-UI CSS resources.  What problems or issues can I expect if I include only jquery-ui.js?

Comment: By "safely," do you mean "will it have the right appearance?" - no.

Comment: The CSS files are also hosted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/downloading-jquery-css-from-googles-cdn

Comment: One problem is that your site will look horrible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424981/how-to-remove-all-css-classes-using-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You'd go from something like this (with jQuery UI CSS):

[image: jquery ui w/css]

### To something like this (no jQuery UI CSS):

[image: jquery ui w/out css]

---

Use the link @Ates Goral posted in comments

or

[Xavi - Links to jQuery UI CSS themes hosted on Google's CDN](http://the-xavi.com/articles/jquery-ui-css-themes-hosted-on-cdn)

for a hosted stylesheet

---

**Update:**

For reference sake, the path for the Google CDN jQuery UI CSS is

http://
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/**[version]**/themes/**[theme]**/jquery-ui.css

example:

[http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/**1.8.13**/themes/**base**/jquery-ui.css](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css)

**Versions:**

1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13

**Themes:**

base, black-tie, blitzer, cupertino, dark-hive, dot-luv, eggplant, excite-bike, flick, hot-sneaks, humanity, le-frog, mint-choc, overcast, pepper-grinder, redmond, smoothness, south-street, start, sunny, swanky-purse, trontastic, ui-darkness, ui-lightness, vader