# Jquery addClass is not persistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, addclass

I have a web application that I'm developing in Django. I wnat to have a simple way to track where the user is on the site.
So I thought I would change the css of the item clicked on the menu.

I added this simple piece of code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".up_menu_item").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("green");
                var excludeThis = $(this);
                $(".up_menu_item").not(excludeThis).each(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass("green");
                });
        });

        });
        </script>
```

When I click on the menu item, the color changes, but it turns back to default right after. The item I click on are actually  tags which redirect the user to another url. But the menu (and the javascript) is always included in the urls called, so I thought the class would stay.

I don't know if I'm very clear, but I would appreciate any help as this is starting to drive me crazy!

Comment: When you reload your page everything on the page will be reload.. so your classes will be reset... So you need to save the users clicks so you can add the classes on page load

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: If you have different pages, you can set the class 'green' in your markup already and your jquery code would be unnecessary.

Comment: yes if you load the content via ajax that will be avoided

Comment: I redirect like that `<a id="projet_menu" class="up_menu_item" href="{% url projet_menu %}">PROJECT MANAGER</a>` In some pages, there is some ajax involved on loading but not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript isn't the appropriate tool for this. As Kim says in the comment, when you reload the page, your class won't be present any more.

Since you're using Django, the way to do this is in the Django template - for each url in your menu, check if it matches the current URL, and add the class if so.

**Edit** You can get the current URL from `request.path`, assuming you've passed the request into your template (this happens automatically if you've enabled the [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request)).

Comment: I'm still new to Django, how do you check the current URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to remove the class from all elements before readding it to the new element?

```
$(".up_menu_item").click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('class')).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("green");
});
```

Comment: Got no idea what you're trying to do here... besides, there is no removeClass() with no parameter in jQuery...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424981/how-to-remove-all-css-classess-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

When you go to another page, all changes applied with Javascript (or jQuery naturally) are gone. The page is loaded like it normally would. All changes made are applied on the **current displaying page only**. It does not modify pages that come after.

You could check what page is opened when the page is loaded, and change the colour of the corresponding button. The best way to go is use your server-side programming language (which in your case is Python with the Django framework) to add the class, if the page matches the right button.

Comment: I kinda hoped I wouldn't have to do that :p How do you check what page is open ?

Comment: I've never programmed in Python so I cant help you with that haha!

Comment: It was worth asking! But I guess it's not such a difficult question. The only thing is I also have "sub-menus", this might be hard to handle by checking the current url