# How can I remove all classes from an element?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove all CSS classes using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424981/how-to-remove-all-css-classes-using-jquery)

I have the following:

```
<div id="abc">
</div>
```

Inside that div there can be one only of the following:

```
<p class="message">
<p class="message error"></p>
<p class="message warning"></p>
<p class="message success"></p>
<p class="message loading"></p>
```

Is there a way that I can find and remove all classes from the `<p>` element?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("#abc p").attr("class", "");
```

or

```
$("#abc p").removeClass();
```

Comment: What are you talking about, the jquery documentation doesn't say it's supported?  The first line of the documentation says exactly that.

Comment: It does directly say it, in the 2nd sentence of the first paragraph of the description of the function in the API doc

Comment: OK, I didn't see that in the doc.  You're right, it is supported there.  Looking in the code, it does `elem.className = ""` when nothing is passed to `.removeClass()`.  Post edited.

Answer (score 6):

> If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Use `removeClass()` with no arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `removeAttr` method:

```
$('#abc p').removeAttr('class')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#example-2)

```
$('#abc p').removeClass();
```