# Remove All classes From Div

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any way to remove all classes from div ... on click of image. I want to remove all the classes from it.

Please Help,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function(){
        var pos=$('img', this).attr('alt');
        alert('i am imageFlip'+this.alt);           

        console.log('i am Image Flip');
        var t = $(this);

        t.prevAll().removeClass('lower').addClass('t1');
        t.nextAll().removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
    });
});
```

Here in my code, I want to remove all classes from `$(this)`.

Comment: may be dupe of [how-to-remove-all-css-classes-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424981/how-to-remove-all-css-classes-using-jquery) ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `this` in a jQuery selector to complete this job.

To remove all classes from the element

```
this.className = '';
```

Comment: Yay, no real need to use jQuery for this, +1.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan sure, but he specifically tagged jquery but not javascript. He may also want to chain further jQuery functions

Comment: but using jquery will have advantage for jquery method chaining, for example: `$('div').removeClass().text('Hello');`

Answer (score 95):

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

> If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will
>   be removed from the set of matched elements. **If no class names are
>   specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.**

Comment: Agreed. Only because the op's code is jquery so seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 49):

You can use [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) without using any class as a parameter.

> Description: Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes
>   from each element in the set of matched elements.

Like:

```
$(this).removeClass();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it shows the code example without having to navigate to another page.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.attr('class','')` to remove all classes from any element.

**Example:**

```
$(this).attr('class','')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `removeClass()` to remove all the classes at one shot.

For example, there is a `div` with id = "myDiv". You want to remove all the classes that this `div` has, then you can use the below statement:

```
$("#myDiv").removeClass();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.removeAttr( "class" )` to remove all classes from element.

**Example:**

```
$(this).removeAttr( "class" )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).removeClass();
```

Using `removeClass` with no parameters will remove all of the selector's classes

Comment: Hi @Irvin Dominin, can you please let me know what all necessary changes you've made in my answer?

Comment: Yep, a simple code format, I forgot to write it in the comment, you can check it clicking on "editeted xxx yyy ago"

Comment: Ok Thanks. I'll keep this in mind for next times. :)