# Jquery remove style

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I **remove** the `.parent p` *color style* from the *first* `p` with **JQuery** so the *first* `p` can use the *color style* from `body` ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>1. Child</p>
    <p>2. Child</p>
    <p>3. Child</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    color:green;
}

.parent p{
    color:red;
}
```

I tried with

```
$('.parent p:first').removeClass();
```

But that doesn't work because the `color` for `p:first` comes from `.parent p`.

I know I can use `css()` , but I was wondering if I can **remove** the style ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnkDx/)

Comment: you need to set the css `$('.parent p:first').css('color', 'green')`

Comment: I know I can use `css()` , but I was wondering if I can **remove** the style ?

Comment: since the styles are coming from the css element/page you cannot just remove it, you need to override it using an element level css entry

Comment: @DadoJerry [`removeClass()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424981/how-to-remove-all-css-classes-using-jquery) removes all the classes from the element.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I thought It can be removed somehow with `removeClass()` or some else function. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, since the color is set using the css definition `.parent p` you cannot remove the style, you need to override it with a element level/css definition.

In order to use a element level override use

```
$('.parent p:first').css('color', 'green')
```

Or in your css file add a definition using [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)

```
.parent p:first-child{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Because the `color` is set in the `body` element, `color:inherit` suits better - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnkDx/2/). Thanks

Comment: @Vucko if color inherit suits better, you should have accepted the answer below.

Comment: @silentw you didn't provide a detailed answer as Arun, so I accepted his answer and gave both +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent p:first').css('color', 'inherit');
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnkDx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this once

```
 $('.parent p:first').css('color','initial');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/85zBy/

Comment: This doesn't use the `body` color. Is there a way to set the default _initial_ color?