# Remove class from <html>

Tags: jquery, html, removeclass

I know that this may be an easy one but I got stuck here. I want to remove `ui-mobile` from my `<html>` tag

```
<html class="ui-mobile">
```

I've tried with this

```
$(html).removeClass('.ui-mobile');
```

But it throws the following exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `document.documentElement.className = '';`

Comment: @adeneo, please put your answer in an answer.

Comment: LOL... Why so many answers? :-)

Comment: that was the fastest stream of answers i've ever seen.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - Nah, not enough jQuery !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all CSS classes using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424981/how-to-remove-all-css-classes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things wrong with the code.

1. html should be in quotes, because it's not a variable.

   ```
   $('html')
   ```
2. there shouldn't be a period in front of the class

   ```
   .removeClass('ui-mobile');
   ```

Comment: Seems to be the winner. :-)

Comment: @Johnツ yep : ) Thanks to all of you guys. 1+ It seems that I need a cup of coffee :D

Answer (score 3):

```
$('html').removeClass('ui-mobile');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('html').removeClass('ui-mobile');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach using `prop` saving you a few bytes:

```
$('html').prop('class', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a element selector, where the element name has to be passed as a string

```
$('html').removeClass('.ui-mobile');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement means html is a variable enclose in quotes to use it as tag selector. Also remove dot `.` in removeClass method.

```
$('html').removeClass('ui-mobile');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$('html').removeClass('ui-mobile');
```

It should be in `quotes` like

```
$('html')
```

And dont need to mention the class name with `.` while you are `removing` or `adding` it.It only need while you are selecting with it,simply while you are using it as `selector`

Answer (score 0):

Its very Simple:-

$('html').removeClass('ui-mobile');

**Explanation for the above Solution:-**

$('html') // This is the predefined selector

removeClass('ui-mobile'); // To remove class from the selector your defined.

You can also Add Class like :-

$('html').addClass('ui-mobile');