# Loop "animation" consisting of add/removeClasses

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, delay

I'm trying to loop an "animation" of adding and removing classes:

```
function loading() {
  $('#loading').removeClass().addClass('load0').delay(5000).removeClass().addClass('load1').delay(5000).removeClass().addClass('load2').delay(5000).removeClass().addClass('load3').delay(5000, loading);
}
loading();
```

Two problems:

1. It doesn't appear that `removeClass()` and `addClass()` can be queued with `delay()`.
2. `delay()` doesn't appear to accept a callback function.

How can I do this?

Comment: delay is for fx queues, what does load1..n classes have?

Comment: They are: `.load0{display:none !important;}`, `.load1{margin-left:-48px !important;}`, `.load2{}`, and `.load3{margin-left:24px !important;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var l = $('#loading'),
    i = 0;

(function loading() {
    l.removeClass().addClass('load' + i);
    i = ++i % 4;
    setTimeout(loading, 5000);
})();
```

---

Or we can encapsulate the variables too.

```
(function loading(l, i) {
    l.removeClass().addClass('load' + i);
    setTimeout(function() {
       loading(l, ++i % 4);
    }, 5000);
})($('#loading'), 0);
```

---

Modern browsers make this a little cleaner.

```
(function loading(l, i) {
    l.removeClass().addClass('load' + i);
    setTimeout(loading, 5000, l, ++i % 4);
})($('#loading'), 0);
```

Comment: You rock!  That works great!  What if I wanted this: `load0` --> 500ms --> `load1` --> 500ms --> `load2` --> 500ms `load3` -->1000ms --> `load0`?

Comment: You would test the value of `i`, and set the desired duration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `delay` for non animating functions

Using `setTimeout` instead with your own callbacks might work out better.

Comment: My understanding is that if `removeClass` is called without a parameter, it will remove all classes.

Comment: Multiple sources confirm that it does here, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424981/how-to-remove-all-css-classes-using-jquery

Comment: @qwertynl: Yes, it does say that there.

Comment: Ahh ok. Never knew that.

Answer (score 0):

If we're trying to loop animations why not loop animations using the .animate() with callbacks?

Example Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Culyx/fsxpZ/1/

The "arrow" in the fiddle used to be an image just a place holder div at the moment; but that should be another way of looping animations in jquery. Code for the looping animations:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //looping bouncing arrow animation and speed controls
    var arrowSpeed = 400;
    bounceLeft = function () {
        $(".arrow").animate({
            left: "+=50px"
        }, {
            duration: arrowSpeed,
            complete: bounceRight
        });
    }
    bounceRight = function () {
        $(".arrow").animate({
            left: "-=50px"
        }, {
            duration: arrowSpeed,
            complete: bounceLeft
        });
    }
    bounceLeft();
});
```